# How can I convert a ModelChoiceField into a display only field in the admin

Tags: django, django-admin

Right now, I have an admin page with a Container and a stackedInline for the Pages.  The pages have 2 ForeignKeys in them and as the # of values for those ForeignKeys grows, the page takes forever to render.

How do I manage to display the value of the ForeignKey, but NOT let it be a changeable thing in the admin?  I definetely want to display the str(ForeignModel) in the inlines, but I don't want a select box with several 1000 choices to be loaded once for each Page model.

I remember reading about this somewhere, but can't seem to locate it anymore.  If it wasn't in the admin, I could just change out the widget, but I don't know how to do that in the admin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you talking about ModelAdmin.readonly_fields?

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    # Other stuff
    readonly_fields = ('myforeignkey',)
```

And, for future reference, it's easy to change out the widget in the admin.

**For a specific field:**

```
class MyModelAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        widgets = {
            'somefield': MyWidget(),
        }

class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = MyModelAdminForm
```

**For all fields of a particular type:**

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    formfield_overrides = {
        models.TextField: {'widget': RichTextEditorWidget},
    }
```

Comment: That was exactly what I was after.  Thanks.